# Show different partial views on button clicks on Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a view and this view contains three buttons. I want to show different partial views on button clicks. I also want to transfer the model to these partial views. I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```js
 <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#title1").click(function () {
                    $("#main-content").html('@Html.Partial("Shared/_Articles"), articles');
                });

                 $("#title2").click(function () {
                    $("#main-content").html('@Html.Partial("Shared/_Videos"), videos');
                });

                 $("#title3").click(function () {
                    $("#main-content").html('@Html.Partial("Shared/_Notebookss"), notebooks');
                });
            });
            
 </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to load all three partials with the initial response. Put them into a `display: none` element or a `<template>` and when a button is clicked either show/hide accordingly, or copy the respective content into `#main-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a work demo in Index, you can refer to it.

The `load()` method points to the Index.cshtml razor page and has handler query string parameter set to Title1/Title2/Title3. This way we instruct the framework that `OnGetTitle1()` handler residing inside the Index page model is to be invoked when the button is clicked.

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<button type="button" id="title1">title1</button>
<button type="button" id="title2">title2</button>
<button type="button" id="title3">title3</button>

<div id="main-content"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#title1").click(function () {
            $("#main-content").load("/Index?handler=Title1");
        });
        $("#title2").click(function () {          
            $("#main-content").load("/Index?handler=Title2");
        });
        $("#title3").click(function () {
            $("#main-content").load("/Index?handler=Title3");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The OnGetTitle1,OnGetTitle2,OnGetTitle3 handler in Index.cshtml.cs is shown below:

```
public IActionResult OnGetTitle1()
{           
    var model = new Users() { Id = 1, Name ="aa"};
    return Partial("_Articles",model);
}
public IActionResult OnGetTitle2()
{
    var model = new Users() { Id = 2, Name = "bb" };
    return Partial("_Videos", model);
}
public IActionResult OnGetTitle3()
{
    var model = new Users() { Id = 3, Name = "cc" };
    return Partial("_Notebookss", model);
}
```

I create a Users model:

```
 public class Users
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

The _Articles,_Videos,_Notebookss partial view then renders the model as follows:

```
@model razorpartial.Models.Users

Name:  @Model.Name
Id:   @Model.Id
```

result:

[image]